# Output line by line with PHP

Tags: php, line

In a small application, I'm writing, during installation phase, the user must enter detail about the MySQL connection in a form (server name, database name, username ...)

I would like to display line by line the result of tests and actions done in a window, with eventually a small pause between each test, like :

> "Connection to the server ..."(2s) "ok" (2s)
>   "Connection to the database ..."(2s) "ok" (2s)
>   "Creation of tables ..."(2s) "ok"
>    ....etc

I have tried with ob_start(), flush(), ob_flush() but it doesn't work as my webserver seems to buffer itself the php output, so the script takes a long time to run but everything is printed at the same time.

I have searched here and with Google, without any result (may be not with the correct keywords)

Can you point me to solution ?
with Ajax may be ?

ericc

Comment: Ajax will not be a solution, have you tried to turn output buffering off in your php.ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this, but disabling caching altogether isn't easily accomplished.
Because on the server side there is some caching, which can be disabled, but there is also a very large chance that the browser is caching as well.

To fix this you have a few options:

- fake it, display a static javascript based "animation" and redirect when done.
- Use ajax, let the installation script `echo` the results to a text file / mysql database and use a different php script to load the the text file / database at set intervals and display the new results.
- Use the newest HTML5/javascript streaming API which is made exactly for stuff like this, it is, however, quite hard to find any good documentation on this.

To disable server side caching, I use this code:

```
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) { ob_end_flush(); }
ob_implicit_flush(1);
header('Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Connection: close');
```

Comment: "header('content-type: text/event-stream');" make the page to be downloaded :-o . The rest of your code make it work on Firefox 3.16/Linux but not in Chrome/Linux and no other combination under WindowsXP :-(

Comment: under WindowsXP, it seems that it was because I was behind a proxy. I will fake it with JQuery (.fadeIn), it will be nice and easier

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [usleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) before every time printing out?

**Edit**

You can use usleep() to make your php script delay the execution so that texts can be seen one by one, it could substitute the use of buffering IN YOUR CASE.

```
mysql_connect() successfully -> print something -> usleep(300)
mysql_select_db() successfully -> print something -> usleep(300)
```

Comment: What is the advantage compared to sleep() ?  And how it will solve my problem of buffer ?

Comment: What advantage? Have you look over it on php.net? The difference between sleep() and usleep() is second and millisecond. See my edit above of how it can replace buffering, of course in you case above.

Comment: Yes, I had a look in php.net. But I don't see the difference or advantage between using sleep() or usleep(), only that I will able to specify time in millisecond. The problem is really at the server level which buffer the output of the php script, and send the content only when the script end

Comment: It's not any advantage to talk about :) The use of sleep() and usleep() depends on the situation of when to use it. Back to your problem, it's a good practice to use buffering than delaying your code, my solution is just brief and situation-based :)